# rspec: test routes with constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I'm using rspec, and currently have a task to test routing.
In routes I have:

```
get ':url' => 'article#get', constraints: lambda { |request|
  Article.public.where(url: request.params["url"]).first
}

get ':url' => 'product#get', constraints: lambda { |request|
  Product.get_publick_prod_by_url(request.params["url"])
}
```

and test:

```
let!(:article) {Article.create(name: "qweqwe", 
                            short_description: "sh", 
                            description: "dscr", 
                            public: true, 
                            meta_title: "title", 
                            meta_description: "meta-descr", 
                            meta_keywords: "qwe", 
                            url: "qweqwe")}

before(:each) do
  Epk::Application.reload_routes!
end

it "should route to article" do
  expect(get: article.url).to route_to(controller: 'article', action: 'get', url: "qweqwe")
end
```

test is not passing for some strange reasons.
Output - `No route matches "/qweqwe"`.

While testing by hands, all code works perfectly, but I want to set up test for it..

Comment: Have you run `rake routes` to ensure a route matches that?  I'm not entirely familiar with what you're doing, but IMO you probably shouldn't have a route that matches '/qweqwe'.  Seems like a weird route to have.

Comment: Can you try renaming the `public` scope to something else? It is a reserved word.

Comment: @mattforni It was done to allow short url like site.com/article_name. It works on site perfectly, I have problem only with rspec test.

Comment: @zetetic you're right, it's just an old code. Tried to rename scope, it is not helping (

Comment: upd: request.params["url"] is not working while testing. Very strange!

Comment: upd: problem is in route_to method : https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in route_to method, that not passing params for some reasons.
In my situation with simple url like "site.com/:url" I can rewrite route's constraints in this way: `Article.find_published_by_url(request.path_info.split('/')[1])` , and it works perfectly.